# Is Guinsoo's Rage considered a spell?

Tags: league-of-legends

**Guinsoo's Rageblade** has the following unique passive ability:

> Unique – Guinsoo's Rage: Deal 20 (+ 15% bonus AD) (+ 7.5% AP) on-hit magic damage to the target and nearby units in a 350 units radius area of effect.

Is this damage considered ability damage for the purpose of Rylai's Cristal Scepter?

> Unique – Icy: Damaging abilitiesSlow icon slow affected units based on their type:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Guinsoo's unique passive is an on-hit effect, not a spell, and will not apply Rylai's slow effect. However, Frozen Mallet's slow effect *will* apply to enemies hit with the Guinsoo's Rage effect.

Comment: Does this mean that Guinsoo's applies other on-hit affects? It doesn't apply BotRK or Wits End to others in the AoE, right?

Comment: I'll have to do some testing to make sure that it will apply the Frozen Mallet effect, but I know for sure that Guinsoo's will not apply Rylai's.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long in accepting. I thought I had already accepted it.